# Push objects to array in for loop: unexpected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For getting test data I want to push objects into an array:

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
obj["var"] = i;
arr.push(obj);
};
console.log(arr);
```

[The result (running in node.js) gives:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnL02.png)

I get an array of 10 identical objects {var: 9} wheras I expected to get 10 objects with the numbers 0 to 9.
Can someone explain this result?

Comment: "I get an array of 10 identical objects" No, you get an Array with 10 times the same object in it. You always push the same `obj` into the array. Just because you change some property doesn't make it a new object.

Comment: You defined `obj` in the global scope, and you are pushing the reference to the same object. To fix it move `var obj = {};` inside your loop so that new object will be crated on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments: clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Object is always pass by reference in JavaScript. Hence, As per your code you are assigning a new value which points to the same address of the object which results assigning the new value to same object instead of creating a copy of that object.

To make it work, You can create a copy of `obj` every time you push it into an object. Just move the object initialization inside the loop and it will work.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var arr = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj["var"] = i;
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```